# Read File and Output in Format

Tags: xml, powershell

i got my xml file wehre i wanna sort out some Numbers.

```
 {
        {
                "Type": "bldr_chair",
                "DisplayName": "bldr_chair",
                "Position": [
                    4062.198974609375,
                    201.51414489746095,
                    3538.89501953125
                ],
                "Orientation": [
                    0.0,
                    -0.0,
                    -0.0
                ],
                "Scale": 1.0,
                "Flags": 2147483647
            },
            {
                "Type": "bldr_chair",
                "DisplayName": "bldr_chair",
                "Position": [
                    4100.68408203125,
                    200.10733032226563,
                    3418.51171875
                ],
                "Orientation": [
                    0.0,
                    -0.0,
                    -0.0
                ],
                "Scale": 1.0,
                "Flags": 2147483647
            },
            {
                "Type": "bldr_chair",
                "DisplayName": "bldr_chair",
                "Position": [
                    4448.24755859375,
                    201.4647979736328,
                    3362.69970703125
                ],
                "Orientation": [
                    0.0,
                    -0.0,
                    -0.0
                ],
                "Scale": 1.0,
                "Flags": 2147483647
            }
```

But i need only

```
[4062.19897,201.51414,3538.89501],
```

Thats actually what i have. I try to sort my number or build up a array but its not easy in powershell to delcaire all benefits what need to hit.

```
$input = Get-Content $path


    $input | Select-String -pattern '\d+\.\d{5}' -AllMatches | %{$_.matches} | %{$_.value
    
    
    
    } | Add-Content $Ausgabepfad
```

i hope you get some tips for me and i appreaciate your help

Comment: That looks suspiciously like JSON. Can you show the whole "XML file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is a JSON not an XML as Mathias pointed out, you don't need to use *regex* to parse it.

```sh
$string = @'
"Position": [
    4062.198974609375,
    201.51414489746095,
    3538.89501953125
],
'@

$json = "{ $string }" | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Position | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

[4062.198974609375,201.51414489746094,3538.89501953125]
```

`$path` path is likely a valid Json and probably you don't need to add the curly braces `{...}`, in that case you would only do:

```sh
(Get-Content $path | ConvertFrom-Json).Position | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

---

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```sh
$json.EditorObjects.ForEach({
    $coords = foreach($coord in $_.Position) {
        [math]::Round($coord, 3, 'AwayFromZero')
    }
    ,$coords
}) | Select-Object -First 5 | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Which results in:

```sh
[[16112.0,578.507,4247.999],[5589.42,196.243,1670.624],[5448.696,193.072,2159.627],[5098.765,196.585,2797.101],[5418.692,197.421,2673.856]]
```

This invariably will be displayed a single line string, if you don't need this remove `-Compress`.

Comment: Ok thats cool and many compact code but how can i say that we dont need to  specified: (:) The code search for the result in my JSON

Comment: @D4MuTz I don't understand the question sorry

Comment: aah my JSON file was corrupted now its working. But my last issu that now all Result in 1 Line
`(Get-Content $path | ConvertFrom-Json).EditorObjects.Position | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Set-Content $Ausgabepfad`

Comment: @D4MuTz you can remove `-Compress` if you want all expanded

Comment: without Compress he is writing all Numbers among themselves with compress behind each other. But i Want alle cordinates from the position in 1 Line next Line the next 3 cordinates... i uptaded my xml pls take a look

Comment: @D4MuTz that's not a valid Json it errors out for me, you can update it and add your expected outcome and i'll try to help you